# Decide to use Factorials or nCr

Tags: combinatorics

Five different bands have been selected to march in a parade. One band has been chosen to lead the parade. In how many different orders can the remaining 4 bands be placed in the parade?

I don't think order matters in the problem so I think I should use nCr to solve. WHat does one mean when one says "
use nCr for when order doesn't matter"? Does "order does not matter" not influencing the result of the problem situation? For the problem solver, I don't care3 about the order of the bands be. For whose perspective would "order does not matter" apply to?

Comment: Order matters, since the question asks in how many orders the $4$ bands can be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem intends for order to matter, in which case the answer is 4! = 24. If order didn't matter then there would be only one way to choose the remaining four bands (choose them all).

Answer (score 0):

The order matters. The first band has been chosen by default and there are $4!$ ways for the remaining $4$ bands to be placed for a total of $4!$ ways for the march to be set up.

Comment: But I could care less about which order the bands be placed. I don't care about the order. You're saying that because different orders of the band would create different formations, the order matters?

Comment: Yes. The order matters because we want all of the different formations of the bands. The first band is chosen by default, for the second band there are $4$ choices, the third band there are $3$ choices and so on for a total of $4!$ formations.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the bands A, B, C, D:

If order does matter, i can order them like ABCD, ABDC, ACBD, etc., then i count the number of orderings (which is 4! = 24).

If order does not matter, then i treat the orderings as same. For example, i only count ABCD and BACD once, hence order does not matter. In that situation you use combination formula which you stated (which gives you 1, and consistent with the explanation i give).